# C# console application won't run on other people's computers

Tags: c#, console-application

I made a small C# console app and right now I'm trying to build it so it could run on other computers. This is my first time finishing such a project, and I've never built or distributed console apps before, and I couldn't find any clear documentation on properly building console apps. So far I've sent the files I found in the /bin/Debug/netcoreapp 3.1 (pretty much the executable, the needed dll's and a text file the app is supposed to read) after I pressed Build , to two of my friends. One of them has C# installed, the other doesn't. The console app only ran on the computer of the friend that had C# installed, but not on my other friend's computer (it was just opening and closing immediately. Also, my /bin/Release folder never gets populated, even if I switch the Configuration to Release. It only filled out after I tried publishing the app, but it still behaved the same as the one in the Debug folder. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Could somebody teach me how to properly build my console app so that it runs on all PC's, please?

Comment: You can find some documentation about publishing .NET applications here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: It's likely the target computer doesn't have a valid version of .NET Core installed. You may need to install it, or make sure your build is self-contained as described inthe link provided by Martin.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question. Don't add "SOLVED" to it when you get a solution. Just accept the appropriate answer, like you've already done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are developing against .NET Core (3,5 or even 6) the machine you are deploying to will need the .NET Core runtime. If you are using .NET Framework the machine will need the .NET Framework runtime installed.

When you publish a .NET Core application you can choose to package the project as self-contained which does not require the user to install the .NET Core runtime.

See this link for more info: [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

"Publishing your app as self-contained produces an application that includes the .NET runtime and libraries, and your application and its dependencies. Users of the application can run it on a machine that doesn't have the .NET runtime installed."